# "Speech marks" (inverted commas) facing wrong way round in LaTeX output (rmarkdown kable extra footnote)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

I have created a table for a pdf document with rmarkdown using `kableExtra`:

```
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
mtcars[2,2] = paste0(mtcars[2,2], footnote_marker_alphabet (1))
head(mtcars) %>%
  kbl(escape = F)%>%
  footnote(alphabet = c("\"a quote\""),
            general = (" \"Another quote\" ")
```

I'd like to put quotes in the footnote using speech marks (double inverted commas). But in the output the first of each set faces the wrong way, i.e. not facing towards the quoted text:

[image]

Is there a way to correct this? like this:
[image]

Comment: The proper latex code would be `\`\`test''` and not `"test"`

Comment: Or to make usage easier, have a look at the `csquotes` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not used LaTeX in a long time but I think the opening quotes needed to be

```
``
```